# MySQL/PHP return posts inside specific time(NOW()) parameter according to timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to show current posts from MySQL Database in columns accoding to my current computer time.

If you see below, [POST0] to POST[4] was uploaded between 6:00 and 7:00, in the first column I'd like to show the latest posts according to my current time.

Example: My current time is 6:50, so in the first comlumn I want it to always show the newest posts uploaded between 6:00 and 7:00. And the older posts I want it to show in next columns
always according to hourly posts, so [POST5] to POST[9] are posts between 5:00 and 6:00, and so on..

What I don't know is how do I get the first column to always show the posts according to my time, so I'd like some suggestions..

```
+------------------------ +--------------+
|            |            |
|   [POST0]  |   [POST5]  |
|   [6:59]   |   [5:59]   |
+------------+------------+--------------+
|            |            |
|   [POST1]  |   [POST6]  |
|   [6:31]   |   [5:58]   |
|            |            |
+------------+------------+
|            |            |
|   [POST2]  |   [POST7]  |
|   [6:08]   |   [5:56]   |
|            |            |
+------------+------------+
|            |            |
|   [POST3]  |   [POST8]  |
|   [6:01]   |   [5:25]   |
|            |            |
+------------+------------+
|            |            |
|   [POST4]  |   [POST9]  |
|   [6:00]   |   [5:11]   |
|            |            |
+----6:00----+----5:00----+--------------+
```

`EDITED`

Comment: it makes my eyes bleed...

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You will have better luck getting answers if your question is clear and well-formatted.

Comment: I'm sorry for all that horrible post, I hope this clears it up a bit more. I appreciate for looking at the thread.

Comment: There is _no_ relation between the first & second column, which makes this kind of thing more suited to application logic then completely in-sql. It would require a full outer join (which MySQL doesn't support, so you need to emulate it with some union all queries) on a pseudo row number to join on. However, doing the queries in an applition & looping through both of them simultaneously would be relatively simple.

Comment: how many columns and rows were your thinking ?

Comment: Wrikken is right that there is no relation between the first and second column. what that means is that for any given row, say row 7, A7 and B7 do not related to one another in the way we view rows as output from a select/join (like, this is a list of my friends and their birthday's and where they work. each row is an item with data linked to one another even if it came from joins. but in your case each row is merely a sort order of slots of how those posts came in during that hour. so it is a completely non standard row in the traditional sense. so you can do this in mysql but it would be

Comment: ugly to build, maybe takes 1/2 hr, then you turn around and not want it anymore. so aren't there more traditional GUI patterns you can choose than to go thru this exercise ?

Comment: its so simple select your post from database desc and than display at the from end in hourly manner. you can do it through php coding. e.g start a tr and repeat td until hour attribute change from 7 to 6 if its 6 than close tr and start new tr and repeat td for the post that are in 6 and so on....

Answer (score 1):

Two techniques. Both rely on PHP logic rather than a query, because as the comments say, the two columns are independent of each other (even the number of responses is not equal)

- Technique 1: run one query, returning posts in time order, latest first. That's your SQL, it's really simple. You could restrict how many you get with a limit, or how far back with where. That's your SQL.
  Then using PHP, run a loop that goes through the records and displays the hour's posts, until the timestamp indicates a different hour; followed by a second loop to display earlier posts.
- Technique 2: run two queries. The first will return this hour's posts. The second returns earlier ones, up to whatever row limit or time back you decide. Then display the data of each query by running two successive loops.

Personnally I'd use technique 1. It's more flexible - say you change your mind and decide you want to hightlight the last 1/2 hour's posts, or the last 2 hours' posts. It still allows you to present the results as you like.

Also, don't present the results in a table. You don't know how many rows it will be. You don't know whether the number of older posts (the height of column 2) is more or less than recent posts (the height of column one). You may change your mind later about whether you want these posts presented side by side or the older ones smaller or any other good interaction pattern that you may come up with in future.

So - instead of embedding the presentation in a complicated query that returns two columns of unrelated data, run a simple query that returns your data in time order, then use application logic to present in the most suitable way. It's simple, it's flexible, and it keeps presentation logic apart from data logic.